# riot each build html tags

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm new to Riot.js and have a problem with building html elements from objects. I have a structure like this:

```
var self = this;

self.objects = [
  { tag: "h1", text: "hello" },
  { tag: "h2", text: "world" }
];
```

And I want in browser get something like this

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<h2>world</h2>
```

this is what I have

```
<virtual each={objects}><{ tag }> { text } <&#47;{ tag }></virtual>
```

and it gives me

```
"<h1>hello<h1>"
"<h2>world<h2>"
```

How can I remove the `"` quotation marks? Or how can I improve my code to show on a page real html tag, not a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://riotjs.com/guide/#render-unescaped-html

> Riot expressions can only render text values without HTML formatting. However you can make a custom tag to do the job.

Create a custom `raw` tag:

```
<raw>
  <script>
    this.root.innerHTML = opts.content
  </script>
</raw>
```

Use it to render html:

```
<raw content="{'<' + tag + '>' + text + '</' + tag + '>'}" each="{ objects }" />

<script>
  this.objects = [
    { tag: 'h1', text: 'hello' },
    { tag: 'h2', text: 'world' }
  ];
</script>
```

It is possible to get rid of the wrapping `raw` tag by using `virtual` tag & `data-is` combination:

```
<virtual data-is="raw" content="{'<' + tag + '>' + text + '</' + tag + '>'}" each="{ objects }" />
```

Live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQxJNfqvdSvWpMk8z0ej?p=preview